# NewbieQuestion: Can I somehow pass arguments to Spring+Hibernate from a DAO?

Tags: hibernate, spring, orm

In the code I am currently working on I came across a piece code where the fields of MyClass are supposed to be set according to the language in use. But in reality the language code has been hardcoded into the Hibernate UserType class. I somehow need to tell Hibernate what language in use, but how can I accomplish this?

Below are versions of the code modified to be as problem specific as possible.

class I18nStringUserType

```
/**
 * Gets a localized string based on the key and current language
 * TODO: Remove hardcoded language value
 * 
 * @see org.hibernate.usertype.
 *   UserType#nullSafeGet(ResultSet, String[], Object)
**/
public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, 
       Object owner) throws Exception 
{
    String key = (String) Hibernate.STRING.nullSafeGet(rs, names);
    String language = "US"; // design-smell. FIX!
    return I18nStringFactory.getI18nString(key, language);
}
```

The DAO that supplies MyClass uses Spring's HibernateDaoSupport class. Can I somehow modify this to pass arguments to Hibernate that tells it to use some specific language?

```
public class HibernateMyClassDAO extends HibernateDaoSupport{
    public MyClass get(Long id) {
        MyClass fund =  (MyClass) getHibernateTemplate().get(MyClass.class, id);
    }
}
```

This is an edited version of the Hibernate mapping. Do not know if it is needed.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="MyClass" table="MYCLASS" >

        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" column="ID" />
        <property  name="description" column="I18DESCRIPTION" 
            insert="false" update="false"
            type="18nStringUserType"/>
    </class>
    ...
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I have *just* been exposed to Spring & Hibernate, so fare gentle on me ;) I am unsure if the question adequately reflects the problem at hand, so feel free to suggest a more telling title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I don't think it's a good idea to apply i18n inside `UserType` (how would you implement `nullSafeSet`?), it would be better to resolve i18n code at higher levels.

But if it's actually required to do so, you need to introduce some kind of "context" accessible via `static` fields. For example, using thread-local `static` field, something like this:

```
public class ThreadI18nContext {
    private static final ThreadLocal<String> language = new ThreadLocal<String>() {
        protected String initialValue() { return "US"; }
    }

    public static String getLanguage() {
        return language.get();
    }

    public static void setLanguage(String l) {
        language.set(l);
    }
}
```

This solution is ugly, but it's a natural result of implementing i18n at this level.

Comment: Do you have any tips on how to accomplish internationalization? Today we pull all the i18n strings out of the database to populate fields of objects. I see that the coupling between language and objects is at a very low level, and the context approach feels hacky (as you note).